# Stripe card adding duplication issue

Tags: stripe-payments, stripes

Preventing card duplication with Stripe API. Seeking a built-in solution for adding and listing cards without duplicates. Using direct Stripe API. Need a simple approach.

I'm trying to prevent card duplication when adding or listing cards using the Stripe API. Is there an inbuilt function in Stripe that can help with this issue? I'm currently using the direct API from Stripe to handle card operations.

I've encountered a problem where cards are successfully added multiple times, and the same card is listed multiple times as well. I'd like to limit this behavior and prevent card duplication during the card addition process or when listing cards.

Is there a simple solution or a built-in feature in Stripe that can help me achieve this

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t - assuming I understand your issue anyway.

> I'm currently using the direct API from Stripe

This sounds like you’re manually creating Payment Methods (or older Tokens).
If you create a Payment Method, Stripe will return one. There is no notion of duplicate in this matter.
The same card created twice will have different Stripe Token IDs, therefore this isn’t duplication as far as Stripe is concerned.

What I’d suggest is for you to implement a garbage disposal routine, which lists your Customer’s PaymentMethods and deletes (=detaches) them if they have duplicate fingerprints.

Instead of deleting them, you could just not show them. There isn’t really any issue with them (unless there are 200 of them, that’s the limit per Customer)